# Call PHP function with JavaScript Ajax to get database values

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

i try to call a php function with Ajax. This is my JavaScript code in my html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajax(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "SQLCommunication.php",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success : function(json){
                json = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
                alert(json.value);
            }
        }
        )
    }

    $("#btn_refresh").click(function(){
       ajax(); 
    });
</script>
```

I don't know if i have to specify which PHP function i actually want to call? I also don't know how i do that.

My PHP function:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
function readValue(){
    $conn = establishConnection();
    if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT datetime, value FROM tempvalues";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $arr["datetime"] = $row["datetime"]; //return datetime and value as array
        $arr["value"] = $row["value"];
        if(is_ajax()){
            return json_encode($arr);
        } else {
            return $arr;
        }
    }

    $conn->close();
}
```

So the problem is now, that nothing happens if i press the button.

Comment: try `print_r(json_encode($arr))`

Comment: You need to invoke the `readValue()` function in your PHP code and `echo` its result.

Comment: And you don't need to call `parseJSON` as I know

Comment: Also make sure you hit that `readValue` function in your controller.

Comment: Is it wordpress `is_ajax()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll rewrite to my style

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btn_refresh").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "SQLCommunication.php",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success : function(data){
                console.log(data);
                if(data.status === "success"){
                    alert("success");
                }else{
                    alert("error");
                }
            }
            error : function(XHR, status){
                 alert("fatal error");
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
function readValue(){
    $conn = establishConnection();
    if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT datetime, value FROM tempvalues";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $arr["datetime"] = $row["datetime"]; //return datetime and value as array
        $arr["value"] = $row["value"];
        $arr["status"] = "success";
    }else{
        $arr["status"] = "error";
    }

    return json_encode($arr);
    $conn->close();
}

echo readValue();
```

Untested

---

Updated

functions.php

```
function readValue(){
    $conn = establishConnection();
    if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT datetime, value FROM tempvalues";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $arr["datetime"] = $row["datetime"]; //return datetime and value as array
        $arr["value"] = $row["value"];
        $arr["status"] = "success";
    }else{
        $arr["status"] = "error";
    }

    return json_encode($arr);
    $conn->close();
}

function writeValue(){
     ...
}
```

SQLCommunication.php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if(!isset($_GET['func']) && empty($_GET['func'])){
   //make the file inaccessible without $_GET
   $arr['status'] = "error";
   echo json_encode($arr);
   exit();
)

if($_GET['func'] === "readvalue"){
   echo readValue();
}elseif($_GET['func'] === "writevalue"){
   echo writeValue();
}elseif($_GET['func'] === "whatever"){
   //whatever...
}

  ....
```

jQuery

```
$("#btn_refresh").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "SQLCommunication.php?func=readvalue", //SQLCommunication.php?func=writevalue
        dataType: "JSON",
        success : function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if(data.status === "success"){
                alert("success");
            }else{
                alert("error");
            }
        }
        error : function(XHR, status){
             alert("fatal error");
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: thanks, that works. So  i can't indicate which function of the .php - file i want to use? The ajax thing just gives me the echo of the php file. So basically, if i want to call more php functions i have to make a new file for every one?

Comment: @binaryBigInt That's a broad question, well, for me. For the code up there? You can save the functions like `readValue()` up there in `functions.php`, you name it. Access the functions.php through `SQLCommunication.php`. Then, use $_GET method on `SQLCommunication.php`. That's how to make it dynamic, at least what's on my mind right now. I can update my answer if you want it.

Comment: Yes, please give me a short example of what you mean. That would be very helpfull!

Comment: Thanks for your updated post but now i am getting an error: http://pastebin.com/01jXS1XG

Comment: @binaryBigInt What kind of error? Post on another question, please.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the result in your ajax response, you have to use echo(), or any other printing method in your controller instead of return

Comment: What do you mean with "controller"?

Comment: Script or function if you prefer.
Controllers are code file's name in MVC architecture (like Symfony or Laravel for PHP).